# New to pi, strange GPIO behavior

Tags: gpio

A simple issue I hope. I export, set direction, then set value to HI. Perfect, get everything I expect from GPIO 4. Now, once I set value LO, perfect, goes to 0v, but then as soon as I unexport, the pin jumps back to HI.

I have the RPI 3. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the GPIO is set back to INPUT mode when unexported.

All GPIO have software selectable internal pulls to 3V3 and ground.  They may be enabled in software to default the GPIO high or low in the absence of a stronger external voltage.

When a GPIO is switched to an INPUT the default pull will then apply.

In the case of GPIO 4 the default pull is high to 3V3.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your second sentence, the wording is throwing me off.